# How To Install The GNOME 2 Fork 'Mate' Desktop (or similar)  On Fedora linux?

Tags: fedora, gnome

I am running Fedora 16 and keep wanting to do something about the awkward Desktop. I tried several shell extensions but wasn't satisfied with the results, then I heard about MATE, is there a tutorial on how to install it?

Comment: Just FYI, Mate is not your only choice anymore: There's [Cinnamon](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/cinnamon-gnome-shell-fork-with-gnome2.html) now, too, taking the approach of forking GNOME Shell to create a GNOME2-ish experience. ([Github repository](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon))

Comment: Is there something similar to ["MGSE" (Mint Gnome Shell Extensions)](http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_lisa_whatsnew.php#gnome3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MATE-desktop wiki](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download#fedora) reports an update on availability of MATE for Fedora:

> *News since 2012/01/20*: Wolfgang Ulbrich built experimental MATE x86_64 rpms for Fedora 16. To install them, follow those steps:
>
> ```
> yum install http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49862637/Mate-desktop/mate-desktop-fedora/releases/16/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/mate-desktop-release-16-5.fc16.noarch.rpm
> yum groupinstall MATE-Desktop
> ```

Works for me.  About 67 packages get installed, and then at the login screen, I have both GNOME and MATE as available options.